# R: Extracting data from SpatRaster using points in sf class

Tags: r, dem, sf, terra

I have several SpatRasters including: `dem`, `dem_slope`, `dem_ascpect`, `dem_TPI`, `dem_TRI`, `dem_TRIriley`, `dem_TRIrmsd`, `dem_roughness`, `dem_flowdir`. I also have sf class with x and y coordinates and one attribute.

How can I extract data from all of these SpatRasters using locations of sf class points and make a table with extracted data, attribute from sf class and locations of the points?

Here is what I've tried:

```
library(RSAGA)
library(terra)
library(sf)

data("landslides", package = "RSAGA")

dmt <- rast(dem$data)
dmt_slope <- terrain(dmt, v="slope")
dmt_aspect <- terrain(dmt, v="aspect")
dmt_TPI <- terrain(dmt, v="TPI")
dmt_TRI <- terrain(dmt, v="TRI")
dmt_TRIriley <- terrain(dmt, v="TRIriley")
dmt_TRIrmsd <- terrain(dmt, v="TRIrmsd")
dmt_roughness <- terrain(dmt, v="roughness")
dmt_flowdir <- terrain(dmt, v="flowdir")

str(landslides)
landslides_xy <- st_as_sf(x = landslides,coords = c("x","y"))
geom = st_as_sfc(landslides_xy)
landslides_sf <- st_sf(landslides$lslpts,geometry = geom )

dmt_ex <- extract(dmt,landslides_sf)
dmt_slope_ex <- extract(dmt_slope,landslides_sf)
```

When I run the last two commands I get:

> Warning message: In class(object) <- "environment" :   Setting
> class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no
> longer be an S4 object

Comment: Hard to tell without your data. I can't really work out what you are doing with the `landslides` object at the end. If you plot `dmt` and `landslides_sf` do they map as expected?

Comment: I've added some code to show where I've got the data from. They do map as expected.

Comment: I don't get that error, but the data doesn't map together correctly so my output is all NA values. `dmt` comes from `dem$data` which is a bare matrix, so `dmt` has 1x1 pixels and coordinates from 1 to 415 and 1 to 383 (it width and height), whereas `landslides_sf` is a spatial object with points in some coordinate system with values in the 700,000s and 9 millions. The specification of the coordinate system is missing. But now we know the data I think I can write code to do what you want.

Comment: I thought maybe your error was related to the use of `library(tidyverse)` which is bad practice since it pulls in so many extra packages, and in this code you don't even use it, but the code works for me with or without it, so I don't quite understand your error yet.

Comment: Have you tried `vect(landslides_sf)`? You may wat to also assign the csr to the vector object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to properly convert the RSAGA `dem` object to a `terra` raster - this involves using the header information to set the extent of the matrix as well as the coordinate system.  I had a quick look for a function to do this already (maybe in the `RSAGA` package but no joy) so I wrote one:

```
Rd.to.rast <- function(rd){
    m = terra::rast(rd$data)
    xmax = rd$header$xllcorner + rd$header$ncol*rd$header$cellsize
    ymax = rd$header$yllcorner + rd$header$nrow*rd$header$cellsize
    ext(m) = c(rd$header$xllcorner, xmax, rd$header$yllcorner, ymax)
    terra::crs(m) <- rd$header$proj4string
    m[m == rd$header$nodata_value] <- NA
    m
}
```

I think my interpretation of the headers is correct - `xll-` and `yllcorner` are the coordinates of the lower-left point of the lower left cell (not the cell centre, which is in `xllcenter`).

So we do:

```
dmt = Rd.to.rast(dem)
```

Converting the landslides data frame to `sf` seems straightforward since it is coordinates in the same system as the grid:

```
landslides_sf <- st_as_sf(landslides, coords=c("x","y"), crs=crs(dmt))
```

Plotting these two things should show them on the same map:

```
> plot(dmt)
> plot(landslides_sf$geom, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Looks good.

Now you can do the `extract`:

```
> dmt_ex <- extract(dmt,landslides_sf)
> head(dmt_ex)
  ID    lyr.1
1  1 2012.083
2  2 2109.882
3  3 1905.518
4  4 2029.965
5  5 2287.929
6  6 2203.821
```

Here you see a two-column data frame of the `dmt` value at each point. It also works for your derived quantities:

```
> dmt_slope <- terrain(dmt, v="slope")
> dmt_slope_ex <- extract(dmt_slope,landslides_sf)
> head(dmt_slope_ex)
  ID    slope
1  1 40.42438
2  2 30.89278
3  3 51.78051
4  4 43.84574
5  5 15.25398
6  6 52.27879
```

Notice I've still not got to the bottom of your error message, but please take my advice to not ever use `library(tidyverse)` (because it brings in so many packages). If you need a package from the tidyverse, get it individually (eg `library(dplyr)` but again, only if you need it. Your code example doesn't use any packages apart from `terra`, `sf` and `RSAGA`.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank You very much!